If I swirl water in a cup in a zero gravity zone like outer space will the water ever stop spinning?
was just thinking about this in class and it poped into my head while someone was spinning their water in their waterbottle

Welcome to Phys SE. Things to think about: Is the cup you swirl it in frictionless?


Will the water ever stop spinning?

Yes. Friction between the water and the walls of its container, as well as internal friction between different layers of water (called viscosity), will mean that the water will gradually lose energy and will eventually stop spinning.

But will it ever stop spinning in space?

@RylieKutzke friction exists independently of gravity.

Thank you @paulina
